# How can I get Kindle for PC to work in Ubuntu using Wine?

Tags: wine, ebooks, kindle

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kindle for PC via Wine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14686/kindle-for-pc-via-wine)

I've 'installed' Kindle using Wine but it doesn't work. The menu item is there but nothing seems to happen when I click it. I have set the application settings in Wine config to run Kindle as Windows 98 as I've seen suggested... still no luck.

Any experience with this?

EDIT
I don't have a kindle, but I use kindle for android. I was wanting to be able to read my books on my pc without having to use windows.