# Kindle for PC via Wine

Tags: wine, ebooks, kindle

I really want to get the Kindle PC program running on my computer so I can download, read, and manage my e-books. I realize that Calibre can be used to manage e-books and I do have that downloaded. However, Amazon won't let me download ebooks unless my PC is registered in their Kindle program and I'd like to just keep things streamlined.

I've viewed many tutorials and advice for setting it up. I have Wine, I have Kindle for PC, I set it to Win98, all of that. However, when I try to open KindlePC from the Wine menu or from the desktop icon, nothing happens. No error messages, nothing. I don't know what might be wrong. How can I make it work?

Comment: What kind of errors do you get? What does not work?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what Kindle for PC does? My kindle mounts as USB storage and works ootb (except for it has the wrong icon)

Comment: @jorge Basically the Kindle for PC app just lets you sync with your amazon books (DRM'd or not) over the net.  Shows you your library, lets you search text. You can also load generic .mobi format files in the reader.

Comment: FWIW the [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/232826/53508) from this duplicate question worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

Ignore those old tutorials; the latest Wine beta works perfectly with Kindle for PC.

Try adding the development repository to your sources and upgrading to 1.3.7. In a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.3
```

Then download and run the latest version of Kindle for PC. (you don't need to set it to Windows 98 mode)

Comment: Well, that was simple. Worked perfectly. Thank you for your time! Merry Christmas.

Comment: Please note that current users probably shouldn't try and 'upgrade' to Wine 1.3. You can find working wine versions [here](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=10597)

Answer (score 9):

You may, in addition, want to try out [Calibre [image: Install Calibre]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/calibre)

> Calibre is feature-packed e-book
> reader, manager & more with a swish
> Cover Flow-like browser and the
> ability to sync books with actual
> hardware devices, share your books
> online and even convert web feeds into
> perfectly formatted eBooks – all at
> the punch of a button.
>
> Better yet Calibre cis able to display
> pretty much any eBook format you throw
> at it as well allow for quick
> conversion between formats – more than
> earth for even the nerdiest eBookworms
> to burrow in.
>
> *-- Joey Sneddon for omgubuntu*

[image]

Comment: Sure Calibre is great, it just doesn't understand the current DRM files from Amazon.

Answer (score 5):

While it doesn't help you with Kindle for PC, I believe you can use [Kindle Cloud Reader](https://read.amazon.com/) on any computer with a web browser.

Comment: Had Cloud Reader been available when I asked this question I would not have asked this question... :-)

Answer (score 3):

If the intent is to manage the book on your Kindle, what about using a native application like [Calibre](http://calibre-ebook.com/) rather than the Kindle Windows software? Calibre is in the Ubuntu repositories so you can install it via the software centre or using the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install calibre
```

Comment: I love Calibre, but using the Kindle for PC reader (for .mobi files) is a much better experience, I think.   And if someone does have a kindle, or has bought amazon ebooks, the Kindle app handles the DRM flawlessly.  This unfortunately is a requirement in some cases.  (Props to O'Reilly for their DRM'less ebooks by the way.)

Answer (score 3):

This is working for me.  I have this working on both 32-bit and 64-bit systems.  You'll need to get the Wine1.3 code, and the latest KindleforPC installer.

[Here is a page to download the Wine1.3 .deb file](http://www.winehq.org/download/deb)
Alternately, you can type this from the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.3
```

I didn't have to muck with the Windows98 spoofing as I did for the beta Kindle code, and it's a pretty decent reader on the PC.

Answer (score 3):

Just copy the `.dlls`

from

```
~/.wine/drive_c/"Program Files"/Amazon/Kindle/Microsoft.VC90.CRT
```

to

```
~/.wine/drive_c/windows/winxsx/x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_deadbeef
```

or whatever the exact directory name is on your system.  That fixed the problem for me (Kindle PC version 1.10.1 (40262) dated 9/1/2012 installed on Ubuntu x86 12.04.)

You don't really want to be loading Windows DLLs from random sites found by a search engine: they may be fine, but they may also be corrupt or malware-infected.

Comment: Wow, that really worked, besides being such a obscure solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- I had problems with the PlayOnLinux solution above - it crashed without installing Kindle.
- I had used PlayOnLinux to download the Kindle application, as suggested, but no luck.
- By then downloading `KindleForPC-installer.exe` separately from this address:

  http://www.amazon.com/gp/kindle/pc/download

  then directing The PlayOnLinux Kindle script to use it (rather than download it) it Just Worked.

Hope that helps someone else!

Comment: Thank you for providing the link to the amazon site. Their new procedure to download this program is only working under windows. Downloading from other sites just results in a crash of the program. This genuine program can easily be installed using wine and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I've opted to make a native electron app using this method:

(you need to have nodejs installed)

1. Open a terminal session and install [Nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/nativefier) using this command:

   `npm install nativefier -g`
2. cd into a directory you want your app installed into.
3. run:

   `nativefier "https://read.amazon.com" --name "Kindle" -p linux -a x64`

Your output should resemble something like:

`App built to /home/you/yourDirectory/Kindle-linux-x64`

Right click and run the app. enjoy.

[image]

Comment: If you want a nice icon, grab it from here http://imgur.com/a/iakQl - you will need to add the --icon argument followed by the path to the image.

Comment: One word. Amazing!

Answer (score 0):

Many applications like this have dependencies on Internet Explorer style libraries which will of course exist on a Windows install. I have had to install IE under wine to resolve this in the past.

Comment: Note that Wine has trouble with newer versions of IE.

Comment: Just wanted to note that for the versions so far, I haven't had dependency for the Kindle app.

Answer (score 0):

You must run the installer from inside the `.wine/drive_c` directory.

Answer (score 0):

I recently was having the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04, trying Kindle for PC. Following some clues I saw on forums, the best solution was to delete all files under `.wine/drive_c/windows/winsxs/manifests`. It works but may cause problems with other programs.

But I notice also that the only file to cause trouble was `x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_deadbeef.manifest` - inside the `winsxs/` directory - and that the problem is that this file make reference to three files:  `msvcr90.dll, msvcp90.dll, msvcm90.dll`

If you look inside

```
.wine/drive_c/windows/winsxs/x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4148_none_deadbeef
```

you will notice that only the file `msvcr90.dll` exists. So search for the other two dll files on Google and put them in this directory. For me, Kindle for PC is working just fine now after I've put these two dll files in this directory.

Answer (score 0):

- Install [PlayOnLinux](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/playonlinux/). Also, in Synaptic, etc.
- Run it.
- Click 'install'
- Search for 'kindle'

[image]

- Select it and install.

  PlayOnLinux will use and if needed **will install the appropriate Wine version** for the program. **Let PlayOnLinux download automatically and install the Kindle for PC software instead of downloading and selecting it yourself**.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share a solution for those who are trying to install Kindle on Ubuntu 14.04 and Linux Mint. In my case, I noticed that the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` package was not properly installed by the Software Center App because it didn't show the agreement that I had to acknowledge. I think that the fonts were not installed because of that. So I manually installed the fonts from the terminal using `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer`, acknowledged the agreement shown in a colored text format display, and after that, my Kindle does not crash anymore when I open my e-books. My Kindle now works on Wine versions 1.6 and 1.7 under PlayOnLinux.

For Linux Mint users, they should install the ubuntu-restricted-extras package before installing the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` for some reason. I think without the ubuntu-restricted-extras, not all fonts will be available even after installing the ttf-mscorefonts-installer package

Hope this works! May the Lord bless!