# I am looking for a way to read kindle books

Tags: software-recommendation, kindle

I am looking to see if there is an application for reading kindle books on this system.

Comment: You can 1. try to run [Kindle for PC on Wine](http://askubuntu.com/questions/144463/how-can-i-get-kindle-for-pc-working-on-ubuntu-12-04), 2. use the cloud reader from the browser, 3. use [Calibre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/calibre/).

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [Kindle Cloud Reader for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kindle-cloud-reader/icdipabjmbhpdkjaihfjoikhjjeneebd?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).

Comment: Looks like their website works in Firefox as well https://read.amazon.com/

Comment: "We're sorry. Kindle Cloud Reader can't open this book, but you can read it with our free Kindle app"

Answer (score 5):

[Calibre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/calibre) [image: Install Calibre] has a reader in it and can also convert between formats.

Comment: But how can I attach my kindle account to it?

Comment: Don't bother: Calibre cannot handle the current DRM format of Amazon.